# gitlab ci with conda not using the latest package version

Tags: docker, anaconda, gitlab-ci

I am using a docker image from by Continuum Analytics in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, in order to use conda (as well explained [here](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/gitlab-ci-and-conda/))

Everything works fine except for one detail: I cannot get the latest version of a package published on a specific channel ([this one](https://anaconda.org/PascalLesage/presamples), but that shouldn't matter) - the latest version is 0.2.6, but the version 0.2.3 is installed.

If I specify in my `environment.yaml` file that I want a specific version:

```
dependencies:
 - presamples>=0.2.6
```

I get the following error during build:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
   - presamples[version='>=0.2.6']
```

Are Continuum Analytics docker image not able to download versions of packages that were created after the docker image was created? This may be a silly question, I don't know anything about docker...